# Can not bind to an Observable array

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm using Angular 2 and trying to do some filtering on the array elements before viewing them on the page. The service returns the list of some players with this call:

```
getPlayers(position: string) {
    return this.get(`players/${position}`)
        .map(r => Observable.from(r.data))
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
            return Observable.of<any>();
        });
}
```

As far as I can tell, this returns an ArrayObservable object.

This is how I consume the service in the component:

```
this.svc.getPlayers(this.position)
  .subscribe(p => this.players = p); // this.players is Array<Player>
```

The shape of the data I get from the service is:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": [
   ...
  ]
}
```

So after all of these steps, I get the error below:

**Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'Player 1'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.**

So what's going on here?

Comment: Why are you mapping to `Observable.from(r.data)`?

Comment: Can you post your html code please?

Comment: @AlexanderCiesielski is right. You're accidentally assigning an `Observable` to `this.players` because of `.map(r => Observable.from(r.data))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'Player 1'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

This means you are binding your *ngFor to an object, rather than an array. Looking at your HTTP call, you return an Observable of an array, rather than an Array.

```
        .map(r => Observable.from(r.data))
```

Change this line to

```
        .map(r => r.data)
```

`.map()` already returns an Observable, you don't need to wrap the result in an Observable again.

Comment: Observables can be bound to in templates using the `async` pipe.

Comment: Yes, but the whole point of `async` pipe is to leave out subscribing and unsubscribing to/form observables, which is not the case in this problem.